# If <video> is playing stop <audio>

Tags: javascript, html, video, audio

On a webpage I'm using a couple of audio-tags for mouse-over sounds and a video-tag for playing a video.

Now, when the video is playing, the audio should be stopped and disabled. The audio gets triggered like this:

```
$(this).mouseover(function() {
    $('audio#' + $(this).attr('title') + '_sound').trigger('play');
});
```

Now there should be added something like this, I've tried a couple of thing which none of are working:

```
$(this).mouseover(function() {
    if($('#video') is NOT playing) {
        $('audio#' + $(this).attr('title') + '_sound').trigger('play');
    }
});
```

Anyone made something like this before?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should register an event listener to be called whenever the video tag's pause signal has been asserted.

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.addEventListener("pause", function() { audio.trigger("play"); }, true);
```

Comment: that's the right js way, considering that javascript introduces event-driven programming

Answer (score 3):

HTML5  has a paused attribute.

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

$(this).mouseover(function() {
    if(v.paused){  // checks to see if video is paused
       $('audio#' + $(this).attr('title') + '_sound').trigger('play');
    }
});
```

Comment: See [documentation on `paused`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-media-paused) for more information.

Comment: Also, be aware that surely not *all* browsers support the `paused` attribute.

Comment: @orftz Thanks for posting the documentation. Do you know any good links that provide less technical explanation of `paused`? When I was posting this, I was looking for a link to include that wasn't as verbose as W3 documentation.

Comment: the only other thing I've found about `paused` is [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html). There isn't much doc about this at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var music = document.getElementById("myMusic");
var noOverlap = setInterval(
if(myVideo.paused == false){
    myMusic.pause();
}
, 1000);
```

This will check to see if the two are overlapping every second and by default, play the video and pause the music.